# jaxp_feature_not_supported exception on docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j, jaxp

I am trying to use docx4j on my project. (I'm quite a newbies on it.)

I just try to run the sample code from this link.

http://www.smartjava.org/content/create-complex-word-docx-documents-programatically-docx4j

The input is .docx file and the output is also a .docx file.

And here is what the console gave me when It tried to read my template file:

```
2015-09-10 09:58:43,847 [main] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils  - jaxp_feature_not_supported: Feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" is not supported.
javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: jaxp_feature_not_supported: Feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" is not supported.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setFeature(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:207)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.<clinit>(XmlUtils.java:240)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:686)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3.get(Load3.java:132)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:454)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:371)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:337)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:302)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:170)
    at Experiment.getTemplate(Experiment.java:26)
    at Experiment.main(Experiment.java:112)
```

The environment list here:

```
Java: 1.5
Library Management: Maven
Lib: Version
docx4j: 3.2.1
jaxb-api: 2.1 (Need to add it because Java 1.5 not include this)
jaxb-impl: 2.1 (Need to add it because Java 1.5 not include this)
```

I want to know how to deal with this error.

I try to solve this on my own but got no result.

Thanks for helping me.

**EDIT**:
I just found my answer for this when I read the changelog carefully.

```
V.3.2.0
...
Minimum Java version is Java 6 (since guava and ambassador are compiled for that)
```

I guess I need to go back to version 3.1.0. :| ( and It run smoothly.)

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caught and logged: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/docx4j-3.2.1/src/main/java/org/docx4j/XmlUtils.java#L241

It shouldn't cause a problem.  What happened after that?